# Computing percentile / probability using zscore

Tags: julia

For the following example how do I compute the percentile / probability values / tail area in julia

```
 Example : N(1100, 200) #Normally distributed with mean 1100 & standard deviation 200 for lets say SAT score
 x = 1030 #Lets say students SAT score
 
 #manual calculation
 z-score = (x-mean)/std.dev = 1030-1100 / 200 = -0.35
 #using the probability table the tail area corresponding to this is 0.3632
```

The zscore can be computed using the stats base package.

```
using StatsBase 
zscore([1030], 1100, 200) 
# Out > 0.35
```

How do i compute the corresponding probability (0.3632) obtained from the statistical tables?

Comment: I tried `zscore([1030], 1100, 200)` and it returned `-0.35`. What output are you getting?

Comment: Yes your right! it does work. No clue what I did wrong. Thanks for picking on this. Let me rephrase the question.

Comment: `using Distributions`, and then `cdf(Normal(1100, 200), 1030)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning @DNF's comment into an answer:

You can use the `cdf` function from [Distributions.jl](https://juliastats.org/Distributions.jl/stable/):

```
julia> using Distributions

julia> cdf(Normal(1100, 200), 1030)
0.3631693488243809
```